# Best Practise including code-completion in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpstorm, code-completion

In the following code the "/**  @var BusinessLogic\User $user */" is not enabling code completion. When going by mouse over User in the comment I got:

"Multiple Declarations: this version of IDE will have problems with completion member resolution and inheritance anallysis for all classes that have multiple definitions in project files (regardles of includes)"

```
 public function indexAction() {
   /**  @var BusinessLogic\User $user */
   $user = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('userBusinessLogic');
   $user->setUsername('testUsername');
 }
```

I think Jetbrains is already working on it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2760 and all related Tasks.

The only way I found to enable this is:

```
 use BusinessLogic\User; 

 public function indexAction() {
   /**  @var User $user */
   $user = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('userBusinessLogic');
   $user->setUsername('testUsername');
 }
```

But when I put:

```
use BusinessLogic\User;
```

into the code I can instantiate the user by

```
$user = new User();
```

without serviceLocator; not good for other developers to work on this file afterwards.

Some ideas? Code-Completion is quite important.

Comment: Try adding leading slash before namespace. Your first attempt tells IDE to reference class **relative to current namespace** (i.e. if current namepspace is `\Website\Shop` then FQN will be `\Website\Shop\BusinessLogic\User`). With leading slash you will make it FQN. So ... try `/** @var \BusinessLogic\User $user */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding leading slash before namespace.

Your first attempt tells IDE to reference class **relative to current namespace** (i.e. if current namespace is `\Website\Shop` then FQN will be `\Website\Shop\BusinessLogic\User`).

With leading slash you will make it FQN. So ... `/** @var \BusinessLogic\User $user */`