# how to have symfony autocompletion with eclipse and/or netbeans

Tags: eclipse, symfony, netbeans-8

I have tested symfony3 with both eclipse and netbeans IDE and I still don't manage to get autocompletion...

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php
namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Controller;

// N'oubliez pas ce use :
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AdvertController extends Controller
{

  public function indexAction()
  {

    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig');

    return new Response($content);

  }

}
```

In Eclipse I can have autocomplete for $this (then I have get as a choice), but I never get the render method with autocompletion..

I looked at this [Preserving auto-completion abilities with Symfony2 Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214383/preserving-auto-completion-abilities-with-symfony2-dependency-injection) but I couldn't get it working.

Can anyone help me with my example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    /** @var $twig \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine */
    $twig = $this->get('templating');
    $content = $twig->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig');;

    return new Response($content);
}
```

Maybe you need to adjust the comment hint but it should work.

But my advice would be: Get PhpStorm with the symfony Plugin (i know it's not free but give the trial a try and decide if it's worth it)

Comment: Thanks! it works great on Eclipse. Thank you for taking the time to answer me. The crazy thing is i was close to that but never succeed. Big thx!